# Laravel Custom User Model Policy Issue

Tags: laravel, web, authorization, backend, policy

I am working on a Laravel project where I have a custom user model (Admin model). I am attempting to create a policy for the ThirdParty model, but even when returning true from the policy method, I'm consistently encountering an "action is unauthorized" error.

This is the policy method:

```
public function view(?Admin $admin, ThirdParty $thirdParty)
{
    return true;
}
```

I have registered the policy in the AuthServiceProvider as follows:
use App\Models\ThirdParty;
use App\Policies\ThirdPartyPolicy;

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        ThirdParty::class => ThirdPartyPolicy::class,
    ];
    // ...
}
```

And this is how I am applying it in api.php:

```
Route::get('show/{id}', [ThirdPartyController::class, 'show'])->can('view', 'thirdParty');
```

Finally, the controller action looks like this:

```
public function show(Request $request, ThirdParty $thirdParty)
{
    // ...
}
```

i tried die(); in the policy method but it didn't work
i want a solution to my problem

Comment: I think there is missing information here. What you have given is not enough to tell you what the problem could be.

Comment: what you need else in order to tell what is the problem ? @YoweliKachala

Comment: The information provided is insufficient to accurately identify the problem. For instance, when using the authorize method in the controller, it's crucial to ensure proper authorization logic. Authentication confirmation is also essential, as without it, users lack associated roles or permissions. Additionally, in the method signature public function view(?Admin $admin, ThirdParty $thirdParty), using User $user instead of Admin $admin might be more appropriate, allowing for checks like $user->is_admin to determine the user's administrative status.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i just removed this :

```
->can('view', 'thirdParty')
```

from `api.php` and replaced it with

```
$this->authorize('view', ThirdParty::class);
```

in the controller action and it worked for me!